# Chat reloads indefinitely

Tags: bug, chat

Whatever every chatroom I try to enter always reloads without any apparent reason every second or so. The "Loading [chat name]" pops up, the content gets faded in, and the popup comes back again, loading everything again.

This goes on for an indefinite time - I have never seen it stop so far. This is an issues that only appears on Chrome, Firefox and even IE.

Here's a short demo of what it looks like:

[image: Reloading]

The JS console is silent, and there are not apparent errors in the HTML that could cause this. Still, chat reloads and reloads and reloads,...

What do?

Comment: Can you try flushing any cookies in your browser owned by stackauth.com or chat, and log in to try again?

Comment: @TimPost I tired it - it worked for the SO chat, but when I went to worklpace, same thing happened again. Cleaned all of my cookies and local storage related to anything `*stack*`

Comment: And Only on chrome? Or did you repro in FF and IE? (a little ambiguous in your report)

Comment: Thanks, I just siezed.